# SQL Server XML Column Elements

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008-r2

I use SQL Server 2008 R2 and have a XML column.

I want to have query to get attribute name from a XML column.

For Example the data of XML column like below :

```
<Document DocumentID="214798" Date="02/15/2014 12:00:00 ق.ظ" 
          SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID="123" DocumentSubTypeID="162" 
          Number="12427" Title="2" OwnerPersonID="50599" />
```

I want to get following result :

```
DocumentID
Date
SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID
DocumentSubTypeID
Number
Title
OwnerPersonID
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    xmlColumn.value('(//@DocumentID)[1]', 'int') DocumentID,
    xmlColumn.value('(//@Date)[1]', 'datetime') Date,
    xmlColumn.value('(//@SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID)[1]', 'int') SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID,
    xmlColumn.value('(//@DocumentSubTypeID)[1]', 'int') DocumentSubTypeID,
    xmlColumn.value('(//@Number)[1]', 'int') Number,
    xmlColumn.value('(//@OwnerPersonID)[1]', 'int') OwnerPersonID,
FROM tbl
```

Note, that the `datatime` conversion is neutral specific.

**UPDATE**

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '<Document DocumentID="214798" Date="02/15/2014 12:00 aa" SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID="123" DocumentSubTypeID="162" Number="12427" Title="2" OwnerPersonID="50599" />'

SELECT
    name.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)')
FROM
@xml.nodes('//@*') A(name)
```

Comment: I have different XML nodes in each record of my table. I want to get name list of exists nodes in my XML Data.

Comment: The names you are mentioned in post are not the node names, they are attribute names. Be clear in questions to avoid ambiguity.